# On progress seekbar notification not showing in DownloadManager android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-download-manager

I am downloading the file from webview. But it's not displaying the on going download notification similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW8v6.jpg)  when using DownloadManager. It just doing in background operation. 
How to display the status bar notification when downloading is in progress. 
I can able to get the downloaded file but how to display the on going process in notification?

I used "request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);" but it's not displaying the on going process. Please guide me what mistake I am doing.

Here is my code which I used.

```
mWebview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));
                request.setMimeType("pdf");


                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);


                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);


                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);


                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");


                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                        "pdf"));


                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      //clueless why it's not working..    
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    request.setShowRunningNotification(true);
                }

                //request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                url, contentDisposition, "pdf"));
                dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                downloadReference = dm.enqueue(request);
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
                registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);
            }
        });
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
            if (downloadReference == referenceId) {
                DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                q.setFilterById(intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1));
                Cursor c = dm.query(q);

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        // process download
                        String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE));
                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/Download/" + title);//name here is the name of any string you want to pass to the method
                        if (!file.isDirectory())
                            file.mkdir();
                        //Intent testIntent = new Intent("com.adobe.reader");
                        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                        //testIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        testIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                        try {
                            startActivity(testIntent);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No application available to view PDF",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // get other required data by changing the constant passed to getColumnIndex
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I checked in Android 7.1.1.

Comment: Whats the size of file you attempt to download?

Comment: The file size is 1Mb @Mani

Comment: can you try file size of 1GB and confirm that still notification doesnt shows! my suspicious is since file size 1MB could be a chance it would have downloaded already

Comment: but when i check in default chrome browser, it works by showing notification but the logic which applied inside webview it's not showing notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I found solution.  The problem is didn't enabled download manager.

```
Go to the Settings > App
In the options click 'Show System Apps'
Find 'Download Manager' and open it
Click 'Notifications' under App Settings
Switch on Allow Notifications
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43841708/1921263